# Can I convert XML/XAML into WPF controls at runtime?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there a way to take a chunk of XML/XAML and load it as WPF controls at runtime?

---

> Related:
>   [Can I use XamlReader.Load or InitializeFromXaml from a WPF Window, for the Window definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252199/can-i-use-xamlreader-load-or-initializefromxaml-from-a-wpf-window-for-the-windowhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252199/can-i-use-xamlreader-load-or-initializefromxaml-from-a-wpf-window-for-the-window)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes.
what you want to look at is the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class, specefically, XamlReader.Load

Comment: That sounds like it is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

E.g:

```
string xaml = 
@"<DataTemplate>
    @"<TextBlock Text=""{{Binding Converter={{StaticResource templatesConverter}}, {0} }}""/>
  @"</DataTemplate>";

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));

ParserContext context = new ParserContext();

context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");

context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");

DataTemplate datatemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(stream, context);
```